# Access denied to add Microsoft Graph Schema Extension on a Message

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

We're curretly making a multi-tenant app where admin users can log on Office365 and manipulate other users' emails. We want to add a schema extension on created Message, but I end up with a `AccessDenied` error.
Note that I use the `arxone_path` schema extension, that is `Available` (you can try to use it).

I first set up the delegated permission `Mail.ReadWrite` on my app registration on Azure (like said on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/opentypeextension-post-opentypeextension?view=graph-rest-1.0#permissions ). I also added `Mail.ReadWrite.Shared` permission. Using the user's access token, I can actually fetch, create, delete or update Message of another user. But if I try to update a message to add a schema extension like this:

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/{{user}}/messages/{{message}}
Content-Type: application/json
{
    "arxone_path": {
        "path":"some/path"
    }
}
```

I always get this response :

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Content-type: application/json
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ErrorAccessDenied",
    "message": "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "a95b0641-63e9-4601-82f2-d8c4ed6d64d8",
      "date": "2020-01-16T16:12:29"
    }
  }
}
```

To sum up, I can:

- Edit one of the connected user's own message -> OK
- Add extension of the connected user's own message -> OK
- Edit another user message -> OK
- Add extension of another user message -> NOT OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add an Open Extension to a users objects using delegated access token for another user. You would need to have that user sign in and use their delegated access token.

The other approach is to use application permissions (app-only) and request  User.ReadWrite.All which will require Admin Consent by an Administrator.

Comment: I understand my question was a bit confusing as I changed it a little bit, but it should answer my question anyway.
Does this apply to Schema Extension as well ?

Comment: For Schema Extensions we document what's supported here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/extensibility-overview#supported-resources.
The same access token logic applies here too.

Comment: @JeremyThakeMSFT, I couldn't add open extension to shared calendar events from another user. So the reason is this, right? Then how to allow the permission for the another user? Please answer my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65717070/cant-get-events-with-open-extension-in-microsoft-graph-api)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this [url](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/opentypeextension-post-opentypeextension?view=graph-rest-1.0) says you may need additional permissions (depending on the account type) when trying to create an open Extension.

**Delegated (work or school)**
User.ReadWrite.All
**Delegated (personal Microsoft Account)**
User.ReadWrite
**Application**
User.ReadWrite.All

Comment: The url does say I only need `Mail.ReadWrite` for the message resources. I tried and still have the same result

Comment: I believe your call is failing earlier when you try to get a handle on the user.  Do you have ```User.ReadBasic.All```? Can you try adding it?

Comment: I had `User.Read.All` already, but I also tried `User.ReadBasic.All`, still doesn't work. Also, I learneed that OpenExtension does not support filter (which I need), so I try using OpenSchema instead, but I end up in the same situation

Comment: Are you trying to add the extension to the currently logged in user or another user?

Comment: For another user. I juste tried with the logged in user and it works that way