# Can't get events with open extension in Microsoft Graph API

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I created an event through a shared mailbox in Graph API.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{shared-user-id}/calendars/{shared-calendar-id}/events

{
  "subject": "New Event Test",
  "body": {
    "contentType": "HTML",
    "content": "Mail FLow Test"
  },
  "start": {
      "dateTime": "2021-01-29T12:00:00",
      "timeZone": "Eastern Standard Time"
  },
  "end": {
      "dateTime": "2021-01-30T14:00:00",
      "timeZone": "Eastern Standard Time"
  },
  "attendees": [
    {
      "emailAddress": {
            "address":"calendar@contoso.com",
            "name": "Calendar Organizer"
        },
        "type": "required"
    }
  ]
}
```

This creates an event successfully, and after that, I patched this event with extended data using open extension.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user-id}/calendars/{calendar-id}/events/{just-created-event-id}

{
  "extensions": [
        {
          "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.openTypeExtension",
          "extensionName": "Com.Contoso.Events",
          "courseId": 22,
          "materialId": 75,
          "courseType": "video"
        }
      ]
}
```

This seems not to work. This responses Access is denied.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{shared-user-id}/calendars/{shared-calendar-id}/events?$expand=extensions($filter=id eq 'Microsoft.OutlookServices.OpenTypeExtension.Com.Contoso.Events')
```

It responses `ErrorAccessDenided` with error message "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again".
But if I try this without expanding extensions, then it works.

I couldn't even to create an event because it responded with the same error and message "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again", so I added an API permission `MailboxSettings.ReadWrite` in my Azure AD that made work an event creation through the shared mailbox.

What is the reason why I can create or get events but not add or expand extensions?

Comment: @Allen Wu, Could you help me?

Comment: Outside of code, can you repro the issue with Graph Explorer/POSTMAN as well?

Comment: Also share the requestid, timestamp of the error response

Comment: The method you are using is incorrect. Please refer to [this sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/opentypeextension-post-opentypeextension?view=graph-rest-1.0#request-3) to create the open extension. But based on my test, we cannot use an admin (or a delegated user or a shared mailbox member) to create the extension for the shared mailbox (Even if I have added `Calendars.Readwrite.Shared` permission). It will give 403 error as you have encountered. But when I sign in with the shared mailbox user, it can create the open extension for itself.

Comment: @Dev, I can't get the requestid and timestamp of the error response. It only responses error message when I try to post an extension to an event. `{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorAccessDenied",
        "message": "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again."
    }
}`

Comment: @AllenWu, So you mean only using the access token from the certain user can add extensions, right? I can't add extensions to the other's calendar using my own account, right?

Comment: @Dev, I just tried it again using Graph Explorer. It responses `innerError` property. `"date": "2021-01-15T08:53:19",
            "request-id": "ba2da4b7-c318-4fa3-b4ac-7fedcb0c6586",
            "client-request-id": "9f967061-1d6f-90e5-bf5e-96b364c05a54"`. Hope to hear a good news.

Comment: @hotcakedev Yes. I think so, based on my test result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move my comment here so that this issue is treated as answered.

The method you are using is incorrect. Please refer to [this sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/opentypeextension-post-opentypeextension?view=graph-rest-1.0#request-3) to create the open extension.

But based on my test, we cannot use an admin (or a delegated user or a shared mailbox member) to create the extension for the shared mailbox (Even if I have added `Calendars.Readwrite.Shared` permission). It will give 403 error as you have encountered.

When I sign in with the shared mailbox user, it can create the open extension for itself.

So the conclusion is: when we use delegated permissions (user token), we can only create an open extension for the currently logged in user himself.

Comment: The result was the same whether `post` or `patch`. Anyway, thanks...