# Is it possible to use the application permission token to create a schema extension?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I was unable to create neither an open extension nor schema extension through another user in Graph API.
(Same response whether I try to use Graph explorer or Postman.)

Not sure if it is possible to create a schema extension using application permission from another user.

Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65717070/cant-get-events-with-open-extension-in-microsoft-graph-api).

I succeeded to create an event from another user using my delegated token, but failed to add a schema extension to the created event.

I guess all delegated and application permissions are allowed.

And regarding [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service), what is the difference between get an access token and get an access token after admin consent.

I am currently trying to get application token after admin consent, but not sure if it would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such concept of "application permission from another user".

Application permission is just the application identity (without user authentication).

[This document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service) you mentioned is indeed using client credentials flow which uses application permission (application identity).

But it's not supported to create a schema extension with application permission. See [Permissions of Create schemaExtension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/schemaextension-post-schemaextensions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions).

[image]

**But**, creating an open extension with application permission **is supported**.

See [Permissions of Create open extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/opentypeextension-post-opentypeextension?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#permissions).

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I mentioned the permission incorrectly. Using application token or permission on behalf...

Comment: So you mean I can't create a schema extension from another user, right?

Comment: @hotcakedev You are right. We can't create a schema extension from another user. But creating open extension with application token is supported.

Comment: Thank you for your answering to my question. Btw, how to get the application token?

Comment: @hotcakedev The document you mentioned includes all the steps. The request is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service#4-get-an-access-token.

Comment: So I should follow the 4th step after 3rd one, right?

Comment: And can I use the application token as same as the delegated token? Or should I use both tokens whenever they are needed separately?

Comment: @hotcakedev Yes. And step 5. You should use them separately. Because not all endpoints supports both delegated and application permissions.

Comment: Great. Thank you.

Comment: Should I use consent API before getting the application token each time?

Comment: @hotcakedev Just once.